# Rails 4.2 concern content ignored in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2, activesupport-concern

I'm stuck in a really weird issue. I recently updated from rails 4.1 to 4.2. In 4.1 everything worked fine. But now, in 4.2, it seems model concern content is beig ignored, even if the concern is found.

Putting it simple. I have a `Client` model which belongs to an `Address`, relationship that is defined in an `Addressable` concern:

*app/models/client.rb*

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Addressable
end
```

*app/models/address.rb*

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

*app/models/concerns/addressable.rb*

```
module Addressable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :address
  end
```

No problem in `development` environment. I can do `Client.new.address` without problems. But in `test` environment that same line gives me an `unknow method address` error. If I move `belongs_to :address` to `Client` then it works again. The module is being included, because there is no error about this, and if I change the name to `Adressabledewdewded` then, of course, there is an error.

Same happens with validation methods, etc.

I have been debugging this but I don't find the root. I have copied my `development.rb` as `test.rb` and restarted the server but still. I can't reproduce this in a freshly new Rails 4.2 application, so it has to have something to do with my application or the updating process, but no idea where.

Anyone has a clue?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is the stack trace on doing `Client.new.address` in the console in test environment (in development it works):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for #<Client:0xbc89dac0>
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/marc/projects/clients_webs/a_project/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/marc/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marc/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/marc/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

**UPDATE**

Result of `Client.ancestors` in both environments is (without the only difference of instance identity, of course):

```
 => [Client (call 'Client.connection' to establish a connection), Trader, Addressable, Kaminari::ConfigurationMethods, Kaminari::ActiveRecordModelExtension, Client::GeneratedAssociationMethods, #<#<Class:0xba3b1c70>:0xba3b1d24>, ActiveRecord::Base, Kaminari::ActiveRecordExtension, GlobalID::Identification, ActiveRecord::Store, ActiveRecord::Serialization, ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml, ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON, ActiveModel::Serialization, ActiveRecord::Reflection, ActiveRecord::NoTouching, ActiveRecord::Transactions, ActiveRecord::Aggregations, ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes, ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation, ActiveModel::SecurePassword, ActiveRecord::Associations, ActiveRecord::Timestamp, ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty, ActiveModel::Dirty, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::PrimaryKey, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read, ActiveRecord::Base::GeneratedAssociationMethods, #<#<Class:0xb8df1c14>:0xb8df1c50>, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods, ActiveModel::AttributeMethods, ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic, ActiveRecord::Locking::Optimistic, ActiveRecord::AttributeDecorators, ActiveRecord::Attributes, ActiveRecord::CounterCache, ActiveRecord::Validations, ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods, ActiveSupport::Callbacks, ActiveModel::Validations, ActiveRecord::Integration, ActiveModel::Conversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection, ActiveRecord::Sanitization, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default, ActiveRecord::Scoping, ActiveRecord::Inheritance, ActiveRecord::ModelSchema, ActiveRecord::ReadonlyAttributes, ActiveRecord::Persistence, ActiveRecord::Core, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

And doing `Client.reflections.keys` makes `address` to appear in development but not in test.

Comment: Could you add a complete stack trace of the error occurring, as well as the test in question where the error occurs?

Comment: Hey @janfoeh . There is no need of test to reproduce this in my application. Just opening the console in test environment and doing `Client.new.address` raises a `undefined method `address'` error. I edit the answer to add the stack trace, but I'm afraid it is completely useless.

Comment: You're right, that makes the point moot. Sorry I missed that. Can you run `Client.ancestors` in both a dev and test console, and see if the `Adressable` module is present in both?

Comment: Thanks @janfoeh. In both cases `Addressable` appears... I update the question with its output.

Comment: Hmm. `Client.reflections` allows you to inspect the associations, with `Client.reflections.keys` giving you only the names. Can you spot a difference there between both environments?

Comment: Yes, `address` appears in development but not in test :)

Comment: I'm quite sorry, but I'm at a loss. What I would do next is install a debugger (debugger for Ruby 1.x, byebug for Ruby 2.x), set a breakpoint before the `belongs_to` and step through it in both environments.

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing clear. Thank you very much anyway @janfoech

Comment: @janfoeh I got it :) If you are wondering which was the reason read my answer )

Comment: Good catch, and a good reminder for me to namespace my Concerns. I honestly wish they were by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it. The thing is that a gem that is present only in my test environment (`json-schema`), has `addressable` gem as a dependency, which is defining an `Addressable` module. When Rails tries to autoload `Addressable` it finds the class defined by `addressable` instead of my concern class. The module is being included but it is not the one I thought.

When updating my Gemfile, `json-schema` has been updated and now depends on `addresable`, [since November 2014](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema/commit/3635e43f5c17b2fec533a32b7c3b4add6e3e94f0).

Hard one to catch :)

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour with exactly the same issue, thank you for posting the solution!

Comment: Daaaaaaaaammit.  I've spent all day with the exact problem -- a concern named "Addressable" that works fine, except in test environment.  After I stumble across this issue, then go eyeball my Gemfile.lock, and I find an "addressable" gem being required by the capybara gem, which is only included in test.  Ugh!  I've been troubleshooting my RSpec all damn day!